# NodeJs and npm: The package mocha does not satisfy its siblings' peerDependencies requirements

Tags: node.js, npm

I'm trying to set up the CMS that my company uses. I am setting this up on my Mac. We still tend to run things "on metal" rather than in a VM or Vagrant or anything else. We have a big Make file that is suppose to do the work for us, and "make install" works, but then "make run" is suppose to set up some additional things, and eventually it blows up with this error:

```
> ws@0.4.32 install /Users/cerhovice/projects/eaneighborhood/repos/angels/src/javascript/node_modules/karma/node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/socket.io-client/node_modules/ws
> (node-gyp rebuild 2> builderror.log) || (exit 0)

npm ERR! Darwin 11.4.2
npm ERR! argv "node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install"
npm ERR! node v0.10.33
npm ERR! npm  v2.1.10
npm ERR! code EPEERINVALID

npm ERR! peerinvalid The package mocha does not satisfy its siblings' peerDependencies requirements!
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer karma-mocha@0.1.9 wants mocha@*
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer mocha-as-promised@2.0.0 wants mocha@>= 1.8.0 <2

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /Users/cerhovice/projects/eaneighborhood/repos/angels/src/javascript/npm-debug.log
```

So I tried:

```
npm install mocha@1.9
```

and I saw:

```
mocha@1.9.0 node_modules/mocha
├── growl@1.7.0
├── commander@0.6.1
├── diff@1.0.2
├── mkdirp@0.3.3
├── debug@2.1.0 (ms@0.6.2)
├── ms@0.3.0
└── jade@0.26.3 (mkdirp@0.3.0)
```

but then I tried to run "make run" and I got exactly the same error as before. So I tried:

```
npm uninstall -g karma-mocha
```

because I thought I could start over, but I got:

```
npm WARN uninstall not installed in /Users/cerhovice/projects/eaneighborhood/repos/nixd/usr/lib/node_modules: "karma-mocha"
```

I tried the same with "mocha".

Nothing seems to fix this problem. Any suggestions?

Comment: did you uninstall `mocha-as-promised` too? You should use a vm.

Comment: I don't know why we are running "on metal". A VM would make a lot of sense. We are a strange company, in that we use Docker in production, but not in development.

Comment: In the end, I fixed the problem by editing by hand the package.json for mocha-as-promised (adjusting its listed dependency on mocha). I doubt this is a long term solution. The package.json is blocked our company's .gitignore file, so I'll have to find a different way to give the gift of this fix to my co-workers.

Comment: why would the `package.json` file being ignored by git? It's usually `node_modules` and any other package manager directory is ignored so that the `.json` file can aggregate the necessary files without the need for tracking them.

Answer (score 0):

What type of OS are you running?  I'm not sure if I've heard of a "make run" command in any Linux/UNIX environment.  Here's the reference I used for the make command [1](http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl1_make.htm)

Comment: I am on Mac OS X 10.7.5. I have co-workers, in another city, who have gotten this thing to work on their Macs, so I know it can be done. The "make run" command certainly exists, because it does start to run. But it dies after a minute with this npm error. I am assuming the problem that I have, that my co-workers do not, is specific to some paths on my machine. Also, I am using zsh, whereas my co-workers use bash, I am not clear if that is somehow undermining some of the minor bash commands we use in our build system.

Comment: Glad to see you fixed the problem.  I was going to leave my response as just "What type of OS are you running?", but stack exchange did not seem to like that type of response, haha.   I was thinking it was a version/OS issue, because everytime i try to "run" (make) unstable (no dependency resolution)/incompatible packages or fat finger something, I get those errors.